# "Symmetrically parallel": Redundancy?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, syntactic-analysis, redundancy

In a literary analysis I am preparing, I toyed with the following sentence:
"Sections [A] and [C] are symmetrically parallel."
Am I unnecessarily redundant? Or is there a logical gap between the two concepts?

Comment: I don't know about literary analysis, but in mechanical stuff it's definitely possible for two things to be symmetric without being parallel, or to be parallel without being symmetric.

Comment: In literary analysis, "logical gaps" are considered a positive boon.

Comment: I believe 'unnecessarily redundant' is itself unnecessarily redundant.

Comment: @DJClayworth exactly what I thought.

Comment: . if you look at the broader  definition of symmetry: "similarity, correspondence, or balance "  then parallel is necessarily symmetric, but symmetric is not necessarily parallel, as with  two things going on opposite directions, for example. So: "Sections A and C are parallel" is enough I think

Comment: Hey, you're right about my own repetition. Point taken. And about the logic of the two concepts. Thanks.

Comment: @P.Obertelli -- You can have two line segments that are parallel, but one is longer than the other, or thicker.  And, of course, "symmetry" is with reference to some center, and the center of interest may not lie between the two line segments.

Comment: "similarity, correspondence, *or* balance " two lines that share the same direction so much that they never met to infinity share similarity and correspondance, and balance. But in the mathematical sense you're right.

Comment: to add to that, in fact even geometrically  speaking; regarding to two parallel line segments, they are symetric regarding the tangente that cut them in half. Ie. human face is considered generally symmetric, but not compared to a line that would cut it through from ear to ear, only from top to bottom. Symmetry does not have to be absolute in all plans.

Comment: I understand that you have accepted one of the answers. However, this is a question potentially worth keeping in the repository. Can you please [edit] the question to define *symmetric* and *parallel* as *you* use the terms? It would also be helpful to add some information about the structure of the two sections (GovvieGal's ABC/ABC or ABC/CBA would suffice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you explain how the two sections are both symmetrical AND parallel, I wouldn't use that phrase.
It's hard to imagine how the two sections would be both... Symmetry would look like: Section A: ABC, Section B: CBA. Also called a chiasmic structure.
Parallelism is simply a very close similarity in structure: Section A: ABC, Section B: ABC.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure one could come up with specific technical mathematical instances where symmetric and parallel have non-trivial overlap. But in metaphorical usage for literary analysis they are near synonyms, with symmetry being a little more general than parallelism.

Just use one or the other depending on the context and implication: symmetric if the two passages/stories have additional similar properties, parallel if the linear expression unfolds in the same manner, replacing like with like.